# How to sum values for any x,y coordinate as key in a dictionary by PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates, dictionary, key-value-store

I have a dictionary that it's keys are the x,y coordinates and values are any number example:

> {(232211,3.7094e+06): [83.77895325168048], (232111,3.7093e+06): [176.90244718253913], (232211,3.7095e+06): [162.89507980124253], (232211,3.7092e+06): [167.29352939350477], (232311,3.7093e+06): [60.92259158728928], (232311,3.7092e+06): [155.54956814535277], (232211,3.7093e+06): [86.61996878573295], (232311,3.7094e+06): [56.810704811835954], (232111,3.7094e+06): [175.5288290699763]}

some x,y coordinates (as key) have more than one value (as value), How can I sum values for each x, y coordinate(as key)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a pure Python problem with many solutions ([Sum of values across all nested dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15350749) for example)

```
dicti = {(232211,3.7094e+06): [100], (232111,3.7093e+06): [250, 200], (232211,3.7095e+06): [160,200,300]} 
for i in dicti.values():
    print(i, sum(i))
([100], 100)
([250, 200], 450)
([160, 200, 300], 660)
print sum(sum(i) for i in dicti.values())
1210
```